# how to randomize a matrix keeping the rows fixed in python

Tags: python, matrix, random, row, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to randomize all the rows of my DataFrame but with no success.
What I want to do is from this matrix

```
A= [ 1 2 3
     4 5 6 
     7 8 9 ]
```

to this

```
A_random=[ 4 5 6 
           7 8 9 
           1 2 3 ]
```

I've tried with np. random.shuffle but it doesn't work.

I'm working in Google Colaboratory environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make this work with `np.random.shuffle`, then one way would be to extract the rows into an `ArrayLike` structure, shuffle them in place and then recreate the `DataFrame`:

```
A = pandas.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
extracted_rows = A.values.tolist()  # Each row is an array element, so rows will remain fixed but their order shuffled
np.random.shuffle(extracted_rows)
A_random = pandas.DataFrame(extracted_rows)
```